# No route matches [POST] "parent/id/child/new" error on nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Companies has_many Quotes, trying to create a new Quote in the Quotes controller, nested routes in place, yet i get a;

`No route matches [POST] "/companies/123/quotes/new"`

routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
    resources :quotes, only: [ :new, :create, :show, :index]
    resources :employees, only: [:show, :index]
end
```

rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action

          company_quotes GET    /companies/:company_id/quotes(.:format)        quotes#index
                         POST   /companies/:company_id/quotes(.:format)        quotes#create
       new_company_quote GET    /companies/:company_id/quotes/new(.:format)    quotes#new
           company_quote GET    /companies/:company_id/quotes/:id(.:format)    quotes#show
       company_employees GET    /companies/:company_id/employees(.:format)     employees#index
        company_employee GET    /companies/:company_id/employees/:id(.:format) employees#show
               companies GET    /companies(.:format)                           companies#index
                         POST   /companies(.:format)                           companies#create
             new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)                       companies#new
            edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format)                  companies#edit
                 company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#show
                         PATCH  /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#update
                         PUT    /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#update
                         DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#destroy
                    root GET    /                                              companies#new
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class='form-group col-md-6 quote-form'>
    <%= simple_form_for [@company, @quote] do |quote| %>
        <%= render 'quote_fields', :f => quote %>
        <%= quote.submit "Get Quote", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

_quote_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :lives_overseas, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['Yes', true], 
            ['No', false]], readonly: nil %>
<%= f.input :payment_frequency, collection: Quote.payment_frequencies.map { |k,v| [ k.humanize, k ] } %>
<%= params.inspect %>
```

quotes_controller.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :show, :index ]

  def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @quote = @company.quotes.build
    end

    def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @quote = @company.quotes.build(params[:quote])
    if @quote.save
      render 'show'
    end
    end

  def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @quote = @company.quotes.find(params[:id])
    @employees = @company.employees.all
    # puts debug(params)
  end

  def index
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @quotes = @company.quotes.all
    @employees = @company.employees.all
  end
end
```

Shouldn't the submit action on the quote form be posting to; `POST   /companies/:company_id/quotes(.:format)`, which is clearly present from rake routes?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches [POST] "/companies/123/quotes/new"

You are having *nested resources*, so you need to change

```
<%= simple_form_for @quote do |quote| %>
```

to

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comapny,@quote] do |quote| %>
```

And change `@quote = @company.quotes.build` to just `@quote = Quote.new` in `quotes#new` method

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, still same issue though 

Comment: Do the Quotes_controller methods look ok to you? (aside from your already advised edit)

Comment: @jbk Which version of the Rails you are using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5

Comment: @jbk Then you have to look into `strong params` else you will get `Forbidden attributes` error

Comment: Got it, just created my quote_params private method permitting my attrs 